# What are several methods to kill wisteria?

Tags: invasive

I have wisteria all over my yard.  It's in my neighbor's yard as well and readily comes over the fence.  It's already claimed a couple of trees.  I am also adding an addition to my  house, and there has been some vegetation removal in some of these areas.  And you guessed it, wisteria is now popping up everywhere.  What are some of the better ways to kill this plant with extreme prejudice?  Don't mind using chemicals to do so.

Comment: It's not an invasive species in the UK so no particular advice on how to kill it, but be aware that all parts of the plant are toxic to humans and pets, especially the seeds.

Comment: I would use a shovel and start digging up wisteria starts.  Just so that you are able to see, the wisteria is CONNECTED.  If you kill part of it (usually glyphosate) you stand to risk killing the main plant.  The easiest way to control Wisteria is to cut off all starts.  Water the main wisteria so that it isn't out looking for other water sources or for chemistry.  Have you fertilized this plant?

Comment: @stormy But I want to kill the main plant, and it's cousin, and it's dog too.  I want to go full John Wick/Kaiser Soze on this thing and it's relatives.

Comment: Then add glyphosate to the leaves...a few leaves.  In three weeks cut the entire vine down and put 'brush killer' in the cut off trunk.  You'll have to do this yearly to get complete kill.